numpy's kronecker product outputs non-zero angles outside valid complex-valued blocks
It seems numpy.kron outputs unexpected non-zero angles when applied to a complex-valued matrix, that is non-zero angles outside of the blocks reproducing the input complex-valued matrix. Here is the code generating toy inputs, real and complex:
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Id = np.identity(3)
ones_real = np.ones((2,2))
rand_complex = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (2,2)) + 1.j * np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (2,2))

print(Id)
print(ones_real)
print(rand_complex)

### PLOT DATA
fig1, ax = plt.subplots(4, 1, figsize=(10, 20))

sns.heatmap(Id, ax=ax[0])
sns.heatmap(ones_real, ax=ax[1])
sns.heatmap(np.abs(rand_complex), ax=ax[2])
sns.heatmap(np.angle(rand_complex), ax=ax[3])

Previous inputs visualized as heatmaps :

Now, when the kronecker product is applied using numpy's function, non-zero angles may appear off the valid diagonal of blocks:
### COMPUTE KRON PRODUCTS

kron_real = np.kron(Id, ones_real)
kron_complex = np.kron(Id, rand_complex)

### PLOT KRON PRODUCTS

fig2, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(10, 20))

sns.heatmap(kron_real, ax=ax[0])
sns.heatmap(np.abs(kron_complex), ax=ax[1])
sns.heatmap(np.angle(kron_complex), ax=ax[2])

plt.show()


I suspect this is due to the reliance of numpy.angle on an arctan function, i.e. numerical instability. Still, is this known ? Did I miss something on using numpy.kron with complex-valued inputs ?

Looking at the np.kron(Id, rand_complex) numbers, I see that the 3 'diagonal' blocks are all the same.  That's evident in the np.abs plot as well.  But the off diagonal values are a mix +/- real and imaginary values.  The resulting angle values are either +-0. or pi.

0*rand_complex shows the same sort of mix of +-0 terms.

You get a pi angle if the real component of the complex product is negative (including -0.').  That's documented as the 'C' standard for arctan2`.

kron is just a rearrangement of the values of Id[:,:,None,None]*rand_complex

Thanks for having a look. I see, so without transformation by arctan the result of the kronecker product in itself should be fine.
